# "Mantenha-se sóbrio" usa-se em que situações?

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras

*Mantenha-se sóbrio* é usado quando? Pelo o que eu achei, pode ser usado quando falamos sobre bebidas alcoólicas. Mas só nesse caso?

Posso dizer *permenenha-se sóbrio*?

Comment: Majid, imagino que queiras dizer *permaneça* em vez de *permenenha*? Olha, quando perguntas acerca do significado da palavra, tens o tag "significado"; para como se usa uma palavra, tens "uso-de-palavras", etc. O tag "português-brasileiro" é para coisas específicas do Brasil.

Comment: Pelo menos no Brasil, sempre ouvi mantenha-se sóbrio. Não lembro de ouvir: Permaneça nesse contexto. Além disso, acredito que essa expressão pode ser usada para qualquer tipo de droga (contando que o bebidas alcoólicas tbm são drogas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sentido da pergunta, "sóbrio" mais frequentemente se refere ao álcool, mas também pode se referir a outras drogas. Por exemplo, a Coordenadoria de Prevenção às Drogas de Campinas - SP [define](http://www.campinas.sp.gov.br/governo/assistencia-social-seguranca-alimentar/prevencao-as-drogas/glossario.pdf)

> **sobriedade**
>   1) Abstinência continuada do uso de álcool e de drogas psicoativas (veja recuperação).

que também é usado nesse sentido por uma [clínica](https://www.cttratamentodrogas.com.br/como-faco-para-ficar-sobrio-apos-a-reabilitacao/) de reabilitação e, como apontado pelo Peixoto, em [notícias](https://caras.uol.com.br/tv/fabio-assuncao-desabafa-sobre-sua-dependencia-quimica-relacao-obsessiva.phtml). Também a JusBrasil [define](https://www.jusbrasil.com.br/topicos/295767/abstinencia) um termo relacionado de maneira similar:

> **Abstinência**
>   2) Abstinência é a abstenção do uso de droga ou, mais comumente, de bebidas alcoólicas.

Com relação às duas expressões:

1. **Mantenha-se sóbrio.**

Se diria ao pedir para que alguém não se exceda num determinando momento ou ocasião. Quase sempre sempre se referindo a um excesso de álcool (ou outras drogas), mas também é possível imaginar cenários em que o pedido é para que a pessoa se mantenha "séria, contida", significando, por exemplo, "não seja brincalhão".

2. **Permaneça sóbrio.**

Poderia ser usado para se pedir a um(a) ex-dependente químico (e.g., ex-alcoólatra) que não volte a fazer uso da droga, ou seja, nesse caso, "sóbrio" significa essencialmente "abstêmio".

Comment: Eu também nunca vi *sóbrio* em relação a drogas. Mas procurando, até encontrei (no sentido do teu último exemplo). Não veja nada que impeça. Poderá ser simplesmente que consumo de álcool é muito comum e socialmente aceitável, então as situações em que uma pessoa queira aconselhar outra a moderação ou abstinência no consumo de álcool são muito comuns.

Comment: No Brasil, acredito que sobrio é usado além do alcoól. Aqui tem um exemplo de noticia -> https://caras.uol.com.br/tv/fabio-assuncao-desabafa-sobre-sua-dependencia-quimica-relacao-obsessiva.phtml

"Fábio é dependente químico, porém afirmou que está sóbrio. “Já tive uso exagerado e uma relação obsessiva. É uma coisa que pode acontecer, você não sabe se o uso recreativo vai te levar a isso. Para mim esse assunto já foi, estou em outra fase. É uma assunto muito recorrente, tem uma coisa de estigma que tenho que lidar”. "

Comment: Bem apontado, Jacinto e @Peixoto, obrigado. Vou atualizar a resposta.